# How can I check the fully qualfied method name of a package imported in another python module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two python files `main.py` and `helper.py`. 
The content of the `helper.py` file import statement look like the following:

```
if platform.system() == 'Linux':
   from xyz import abc
else:
   from lmn import abc
```

I want to know the fully qualified method name of the module `abc` from `main.py`.
Does anyone have any idea how can I do this. I am expecting output like the following:
`xyz.abc` or `lmn.abc` depending on the environment context.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What is `abc`? module, subpackage, function..?

Comment: `abc` is a subpackage under `package` `xyz` or `lmn`. These are just symbolic words to hide the actual package names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules have a name attribute that you can use:

```
>>> from xml import etree
>>> etree.__name__
'xml.etree'
```

This is set by the loader to the fully-qualified name of the module at time of importing [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__name__).

Comment: I can not access the `helper.py` file where the import is happening. I need to get this from the `main.py` file.

Comment: Why does that matter? Just check on the module instance, once it is imported it doesn't matter whether you do this in `helper.py` or `main.py`.

Comment: If you have `import main` then do `main.abc.__name__`.